# User defined row, column output in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 2 part question. I am showing a user defined array. User input is # of rows, columns, and at what interval in the array to put a symbol.

1. I cannot get an output of the default symbol ****.
2. Where do I need to insert the interval input to adjust the array accordingly? Inside the function itself or define another function to do this?

I am looking for this result. Input = 1 (row), 4 (columns), 2 (interval). Output would be **?*.

Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int rows = 0, columns = 0, interval = 0;
char symbol;
void Display(int rows = 0, int columns = 0, int interval = 0, char symbol = ('*'));

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;

    cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
    cin >> columns;

    cout << "Enter the number of the question mark interval: ";
    cin >> interval;

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "How many rows do you want? " << rows << "\n";
    cout << "How many columns do you want? " << columns << "\n";
    cout << "How far between question marks? " << interval << "\n";

    Display(rows, columns,  interval, symbol);

    return 0;
}
void Display(int rows, int columns, int intervals, char symbol)
{
    for (int y = 1; y <= rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x <= columns; x++) {
            cout << symbol;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");        
}
```

Comment: Your post and its title mention an array but I don't see one in your code. Please edit your post and fix whichever one is incorrect or incomplete.

Comment: Thank you. I meant it as an array type of output with rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you never assigned `*` to `symbol`.

Change

```
char symbol;
```

to

```
char symbol = '*';
```

Did you know about the disadvantages of global variables. The sooner you learn about the cons the better. [Here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) is a starting point.

Modify the `Display` function as below:

```
void Display(int rows, int columns, int intervals, char symbol)
{
    for (int y = 1; y <= rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x <= columns; x++) {
            if ((x % (interval + 1)) == 0)   //<--since you want after every intervals, just do a mod operation
                cout << "?";
            else
                cout << symbol;
         }
         cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");        
}
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/y4dafM) is the working example.

Comment: Thank you, that covered the first part. I'm still unsure how to have the ? entered in the desired input interval.

Comment: When you say **interval**, do you mean that `?` should appear after that number of columns?

Comment: The interval is a user input that will put a ? every "x" number of columns. Like an interval input of 3 will produce will produce a ? every third column across the rows

Comment: @Macmo13: So why in your example is an interval of `2` putting the `?` in the third column?

Comment: Thank you, never even considered doing that. I will have to refresh on Modulus to make sure I understand the reasoning behind this.